# Why URL is not decoded completely?

Tags: java, urldecode

I am writing a java program where my url need to be decoded and I am using

```
URLDecoder.decode(url,"UTF-8")
```

method to achieve it.But, unfortunately it is not decoding completely. For eg. above method decodes `%3d` to `=` , `%2B` to `+` but it is not decoding few chars like `%3A%2F` which remain unchanged even after decoding. Please tell me if I am missing something.

Comment: Can you give an example of input and output string?

Comment: @shekharsuman it is converting **"%3A%2F"** to **"?3A?2F?"**. it didnt work as output should be **:/**.

Comment: @bidifx input string **40.2%2522%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr1** and output string **40.2%22&url=http%3A%2F%2F**

Comment: is it using some compression format?

Comment: @bidifx 2nd time decoding works. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, everything is working as expected. Your problem is, that the input-string is encoded twice. So simply decode it two times.

**Example:**

1. Input: `%253A`
2. Decodes as: `%3A`
3. Decodes as: `:`

**Code:**

```
String input = "40.2%2522%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr1";
String output1 = URLDecoder.decode(input, "UTF-8");
String output2 = URLDecoder.decode(output1, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(output1);
System.out.println(output2);
```

**Output:**

```
40.2%2522%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr1
40.2%22&url=http%3A%2F%2Fr1
40.2"&url=http://r1
```

**Note:**
If it's uncertain how many times the string is encoded you could repeat decoding until result remains constant.

```
String input = "40.2%2522%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr1";
String output = input;

do {
    input = output;
    output = URLDecoder.decode(input, "UTF-8");

} while (!input.equals(output));
```